# Calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}{dx \over \sqrt[n]{1+x^n}} $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, beta-function

I need to calculate the next integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{dx \over \sqrt[n]{1+x^n}}. $$

I tried doing $u=x^n$ to then develop it as a beta function but did not achieve anything.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which is the result for instance for $n=1$ and/or $n=2$ ?

Comment: is it divergent?

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt[n]{1+x^n}\le1+x$ for all $x\ge0$.

Comment: the exersice say $\int_{0}^{\infty}{dx \over \sqrt[n]{1+x^n}}={\pi \over n \sin{\pi\over n}} $

Comment: I think $\pi\over n\sin(\pi/n)$ is correct if the integrand is simply $1/(1+x^n)$, without the $n$th root.

Comment: I think the answer in exercise is wrong because the answer itself does not satisfy for $n=1$ and $n=2$ Because they are clearly divergent integrals but your RHS seems to provide a finite answer.  The case might have been different if the $n^{th}$ root thing might have been absent

Comment: @Manthanein, the answer is arguably "correct" for $n=1$, insofar as $\pi/0=\infty$. (More precisely, the limit as $n\to1^+$ is $\infty$.)

Comment: @Barry Cipra any comment about $n=2$? And moreover the integral is divergent so it might not be proper to say that $\pi/0$ also tends to infinity so both of them are equal.  We don't generally assign a value of integral as $\infty$ but rather say that it diverges meaning to exclude any further relevance of value of the integral

Comment: @Manthanein, we're in general agreement that the integral as given diverges for all $n$. Specifically it "diverges to infinity" (as opposed to oscillating in value without any particular limit, as $\int_0^\infty\sin x\,dx$ does). All I'm saying is that $\pi/(n\sin(\pi/n))$ also "diverges to infinity" as $n\to1^+$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $x=\tan^{2/n}t$ so the integral is $$\frac{2}{n}\int_0^2\tan^{2/n-1}t\sec^{2-2/n}tdt=\frac{2}{n}\int_0^2\sin^{2/n-1}t\cos^{-1}tdt=\frac{1}{n}\operatorname{B}(\frac{1}{n},\,0).$$This diverges, as can be seen by writing the result in terms of Gamma functions. The divergence is unsurprising, since for large $x$ the integrand is asymptotically $1/x$.